# How I can find specific words in the string and add class (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

There is a text in `P` element. In this text you can select some terms with a mouse click. But I want to display some previously selected words in a different class

I want to find special words in this text and add class.

**Related part**

```
var previosSelectedWords = 'aute,dolor,ex,sed,velit'; // previos selected words
var PSW = previosSelectedWords.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (PSW[i] == words[i]) {
      wrapped.push('<span class="previosSelecteds">' + words[i] + '</span>');
    } else {
      wrapped.push('<span>' + words[i] + '</span>');
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't show the pre-selected words. What could be the reason?

Comment: I get `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` every time I click on a word. Seems like there is no `id="ImWo"`.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @adiga I created

Comment: @HappyAnt This is a just form element that allows post selected words.

Comment: It would be nice if your posted code runs without throwing errors that are caused by elements you didn't include in your code but should be there. ;)

Comment: I have already created the snippet. Just for future questions.

Comment: @HappyAnt This code structure is already running. I am actively using this without any errors. JSFiddle is just a demo. I think there's no point in adding all the unnecessary codes. Do you really need HTML Form code for this case?

Comment: You could also delete the JS code that is causing the error message if it's not necessary for solving your problem. Just look at it from the viewer's perspective: "Hey, there's an error, that must have something to do with the problem...". It's distracting and not very useful.

Comment: I erased a single line of code for you :) The person who wants to help will not see minor situations. @HappyAnt

Comment: I'm just wondering, don't get it wrong please. Do you have any ideas for a solution for my question? I just wondered @HappyAnt

Comment: Well, my answer was messing up the word order. Deleted it, still working on it.

Comment: I just tested your answer. Yes selected words came to the beginning of the sentence @HappyAnt

Comment: Problem solved now...I hope.

Comment: Yes working! @HappyAnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was your loop: You used the same loop and the same index for both arrays.

```
   // Loop through each word and wrap
for (var j = 0; j < PSW.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (PSW[j] == words[i]) {
            var prevS = '<span class="previosSelecteds">' + words[i] + '</span>';
            words[i] = prevS;
        } 
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (!words[i].includes('previosSelecteds')) {
        wrapped.push('<span>' + words[i] + '</span>');
    }
    else {
        wrapped.push(words[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I didn't expect that. Thank you for your help!

Can I ask you one last question? A selected word; example: `people`, but in the text:` people? `

If there is a question mark (or comma etc..) does not show the selected text.
Do you have any idea about the solution? Or should I open a new question?

Comment: I just noticed there still is an issue with my solution when you select any of the pre-selected words. Trying to fix that. And if you have another question, you should open a new one.

Comment: Fixed that by checking if class was already added to the span.

Comment: Hi, I have a new question. I would appreciate it if you would like to review  [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336833/deletes-existing-tags-in-string-how-can-i-prevent-this) @HappyAnt