# Deletes existing tags in string. How can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, if have a font size or a different tags in the text, it completely deletes it.

Before code;

```
<p id="TextHere">[...] <span style='color:red'>people</span> and 10<sup>12</sup>, [...]</p>
```

After code;

```
<p id="TextHere">[...] <span>people</span>, <span>and</span> <span>1012</span>[...]</p>
```

If there are tags of style or class is deleted.

If you have any label in the word; how can I keep that tag protected?

In the full text of the sample code; `<sup>` and `<span style>` tags are available but these tags don't appear after Javascript code works.

*Full Code:*

```
    /**
 * Sentence element
 * @var {Object}
 */
var $sentence = $('#TextHere');
/**
 * Selected words output element
 * @var {Object}
 */
var $selected = $('#selectedWords');

var previosSelectedWords = 'aute,dolor';
var PSW = previosSelectedWords.split(',');
/**
 * Wrap each word in a sentence in a span
 * @param {String} sentence
 * @return {String}
 */
function wrapSentence(sentence) {
  // Get element contents and split by whitespacegit
  var words = $sentence.text().split(/\s+/);
  // Create an empty array for storing wrapped elements
  var wrapped = [];



  // Loop through each word and wrap
for (var j = 0; j < PSW.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (PSW[j] == words[i]) {
            var prevS = '<span class="previosSelecteds">' + words[i] + '</span>';
            words[i] = prevS;
        } 
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (!words[i].includes('previosSelecteds')) {
        wrapped.push('<span>' + words[i] + '</span>');
    }
    else {
        wrapped.push(words[i]);
    }
}


  // Combine words into a string
  return wrapped.join(' ');
}

/**
 * Find all selected words in $sentence element
 * @return {Array}
 */
function getSelected() {
  // Create an empty array for storing selected words
  var selected = [];
  // Find all spans with the highlight class
  $sentence.find('span.highlight').each(function() {
    // Push span values to array
    selected.push($(this).text());
  });
  // Return results
  return selected;
}
$sentence.html(wrapSentence());
$sentence.on('click', 'span', function() {
  // Add/remove the highlight class
  $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
  // Update the selected output
  $selected.text(getSelected().join(', '));
  document.getElementById("ImWo").value = getSelected();
});
```

How do I protect existing tags?

Comment: What do you mean by protect existing tags? What is `PSW` and `words` initially?

Comment: Hi Maaz, I mean; If there is any class or style code in the word; keep them hidden. If you want you can visit [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/Lsh5awr2/10/)

Comment: Sorry. It's still not clear. Could you post the contents of `words` and `PSW`? It might help answer the question.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb You see; `<span style>` & `<sup>` tags is disappeared